# Raven appears to generate incorrect Lucene query for DateTime

Tags: ravendb

I have some documents stored in Raven, which have a CreationDate property, of type "DateTimeOffset".
I have been attempting to get these documents returned in a query from C#, and they are never returned if I use the CreationDate in the query criteria.

After watching the Raven console, I saw the query being issued was:

```
        Query: (FeedOwner:25eb541c\-b04a\-4f08\-b468\-65714f259ac2) AND ( Creati
onDate:[20120524120000000 TO NULL] AND CreationDate:{* TO 20120525120000000})
```

I ran this query directly against HTTP, and changed the date format to:

```
        Query: (FeedOwner:25eb541c\-b04a\-4f08\-b468\-65714f259ac2) AND ( Creati
onDate:[2012-05-24120000000 TO NULL] AND CreationDate:{* TO 2012-05-25120000000})
```

And now it works - it returns my documents which DEFINITELY fall within the range.
Is Raven generating the incorrect date format for lucene? If so, how do I fix this?

Notes:

1. Yes I need time zone support
2. Yes I need Time aswell as Date in my index.

Thanks

[EDIT]
Err... I just changed my entities to use DateTime, just for giggles... and it still fails to return the data... whats going on??? Im using RavenDB.Server.1.2.2002-Unstable

Comment: I have rolled the server back to "RavenDB 1.0.910-Unstable" and it the exact same query, yields results... So there is something wrong with the latest (unstable) Raven Server

Comment: Are you using the same version of Client and Server?

Comment: Actually, No, I was using the latest stable client... is that likely to have been the problem?

Comment: I think so, try using the same version of client and server. Build 1.2.XXX is a new version and I *think* there were some breaking changes regarding how dates are used,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam,
You are using RavenDB Server 1.2 pre release bits with the RavenDB Client 1.0 Stable.
Those are incompatible.