# How to get the generated Lucene query from a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, lucene, ravendb

I have an expression built with Dynamic Linq that is used to query a RavenDb. I would like to be able to view the generated Lucene query so that I can evaluate if it's performant or not. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746833/raven-appears-to-generate-incorrect-lucene-query-for-datetime) a mention of the RavenDB console but I'm trying to get the query in a unit test where the db is in memory. Is there any way to get the Lucene query generated for the filter below?

```
var filteredPersons = persons.AsQueryable().Where(expression);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ToString()` in order to get the Lucene query.

An example:

```
session.Query<Person>.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToString()
```